# What is the difference between array notation and object notation when creating multiple chunks in webpack?

Tags: javascript, configuration, webpack, chunks, webpack-dev-server

I have Hot Reloading feature turned on in my project like this

```
entry: [
    'webpack-hot-middleware/client',
    './src/js/entry.js'
],
output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/'
},
```

Everything works OK until I decided to move vendors modules in different file and it didn't work. Then I realize that creating multiple chunks with array (as mentioned before) somehow differs from creating with object notation llike this

```
entry: {
    hot: 'webpack-hot-middleware/client',
    app: './src/js/entry.js'
},
output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/'
}
```

I included both `app.bundle.js` and `hot.bundle.js` in my `index.html` but still this does not work. Any idea why?

Comment: Well, the two are definitely different. What did you hope to accomplish by switching from an array to an object with named properties?

Comment: I want to include yet another chunk `vendors`

Comment: a difference is that property order in objects are not guaranteed in JavaScript

Comment: but I guarantee it by including in my `index.html`

Comment: Well when you say it "does not work", what *does* happen? Do you get errors somewhere?

Comment: Hot Reload feature does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to specify several chunks you can just add hot-loading script to one of them:

```
entry: {
    vandor: './vendor/vendor.js',
    app: ['webpack-hot-middleware/client', './src/js/entry.js']
},
```

And if you want, you can do it dynamically:

```
entry: {
    vandor: ['./vendor/vendor.js'],
    app: ['./src/js/entry.js']
},
...
webpackConfig.entry.app.unshift('webpack-hot-middleware/client');
```

Comment: Nice. I didn't know that it's possible to pass array instead of string in object notation.